# How can I sort posts by the date and a custom meta field?

Tags: posts, custom-field, wp-query, post-meta, order

I have `custom meta field` that I use for the post `rating`.
So I want to display posts by the `date` and the `rating`, but only for the posts that have specific rating.

For example, I want to display posts with rating above 3, and in this order: by the rating (highest first), but grouped by the date (today's best rated, then yesterday's best rated, etc.).

Can I do it with `WP_Query($args=array())` class?

Comment: Hi and welcome! As you can see bellow, it is possible, but please research this site and the Codex before posting a Question. Well, research efforts are required in most (if not all) the sites of the Stack network.

Comment: Thanks. I was researching but couldn't find it. Then I managed to find it on Google, but s_ha_dum already posted his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, I am reading right out of the Codex page for [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

You want a [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) similar to this with an [`orderby` parameter with the two values you want to order by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters). The first is dominant.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'value' => 3,
            'compare' => '>'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'rating post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I don't know what your `rating` field is named and I don't have your posts and your ratings on my system so I can't test that. Hopefully that will get you started.

Comment: Yes, it works, I managed to find a tutorial with similar solution just before your answer. Thanks :)